# iOS: Property of managed objects relationship has changed, but managed object doesn't notice

Tags: ios, nsmanagedobject

I wasn't able to find anything on this except the fetched results controller problems, which I already solved as well.

But here I have this problem:

My view controller (let's call it MyVC_A) has a property PointOfInterest *poi. This entitiy PointOfInterest has a relationship to the entity Category, called "belongsToCategory" and is n-1. So a PointOfInterest only belongs to one category. So if you select one table cell in MyVC_A which represents one PointOfInterest, you get the next view controller showing all available categories. If you change now the selection of the category and pop this view controller back, the belongsToCategory attribute in MyVC_A hasn't changed, even when I put all the label and image code into the viewWillAppear method.

So I know the property has changed and has been correctly saved in the context, but no changes are displayed. I kinda know why, but what can I do against it? How can I "refresh" my PointOfInterest object in MyVC_A to display the changes?

Comment: Can you show us the code? If you are using a fetchedResultsController the delegate methods are probably a good place to start. How are you implementing -controllerDidChangeContent for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `performFetch:` on your fetched results controller and then `reloadData` on your tableview.